# Error: pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_transform_object: could not find match for var for={(.*?)};

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am trying to get an audio version of a YouTube video, but when I use pytube with Python 3.11, it is giving me this error on the following code:

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xam2U8loUvA')

yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
```

This is the complete error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Utkarsh\OneDrive\Documents\AI Projects\ContentCoach\transcription.py", line 5, in <module>    
yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')
^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 188, in fmt_streams
extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
cipher = Cipher(js=js)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 37, in __init__
self.transform_map = get_transform_map(js, var)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 245, in get_transform_map
transform_object = get_transform_object(js, var)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Utkarsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 227, in get_transform_object
raise RegexMatchError(caller="get_transform_object", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: get_transform_object: could not find match for var for={(.*?)};
```

I have tried [to change the cipher.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76718022/15893195), and install pytube using both, `pip install pytube` and `pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube.git`, and those haven't worked as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71852162/pytube-is-giving-assorted-regex-errors